Segmentation fault on ST_ConcaveHull call
I have a problem on creating a polygon for a geometry by using the ST_ConcaveHull algorithm. Following line geometry creates a segmentation fault and breaks the connection to my Java application.
Executed query:
SELECT ST_ConcaveHull(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-106.03595804557078 35.63135273793611,-106.03599679955283 35.63144617124493,-106.03603556526109 35.63154050604032,-106.0360743194289 35.63163393931828,-106.03611196944472 35.6317273820792)'),0.8)

Geometry creates the issue:

LINESTRING(-106.03595804557078 35.63135273793611,-106.03599679955283
35.63144617124493,-106.03603556526109 35.63154050604032,-106.0360743194289 35.63163393931828,-106.03611196944472 35.6317273820792)

Related PostgreSQL log of the error:
2024-05-29 22:48:27 UTC [101]: [11-1] user=,db=,app=,client=LOG:  server process (PID 210) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2024-05-29 22:48:27 UTC [101]: [12-1] user=,db=,app=,client=DETAIL:  Failed process was running:  select ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(rel.wm_geometry),0.8) as polygon from public.item_area_rel rel                                                                                                     where rel.island_id = $1                                                                                                           
2024-05-29 22:48:27 UTC [101]: [13-1] user=,db=,app=,client=LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2024-05-29 22:48:27 UTC [101]: [14-1] user=,db=,app=,client=LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing

For now adding a ST_Buffer call before calling concave hull fixed the issue.
PostGIS extension version: 3.4.1
PostgreSQL image: PostgreSQL 14.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
After the replay on the fixed GEOS version by @dr_jts
I have also checked the status of the latest docker images on for Postgres v15. As said it is not working on before GEOS v3.12.1. Master image is fine but failed on the alpine.
Docker image: postgis/postgis:15-master
GEOS: 3.13.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0 (Worked)
PostGIS: 3.5.0dev
PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL 15.7 (Debian 15.7-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
Docker image: postgis/postgis:15-3.4-alpine
GEOS: 3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2 (Failed)
PostGIS: 3.4.2
PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL 15.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit

Bug reports should go to development teams, but this is only an error in the sense that bad input shouldn't crash the app.

Works for me on Windows with PostGIS 3.4.1 and PostgreSQL 16.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1937, 64-bit.

fails on 3.3 geos 3.11.2

This is a GEOS issue.  What version are you running (obtained via select postgis_full_version();).

My GEOS version, that is OK, is 3.12.1.

This is a GEOS bug that was fixed in version 3.12.1.
The input line is not quite collinear, and thus does produce a valid Concave Hull.


Thanks for the fixed version info @dr_jts
